# Matching 'AND' across multiple Solr documents

Tags: solr

I have these documents indexed into Solr:

```
[
  {
    "businessObjectId": 4,
    "clientNumber": 565,
    "contractNumber": 421
  },
  {
    "businessObjectId": 4,
    "contractNumber": 455,
    "productType": "electronics"
  },
  {
    "businessObjectId": 5,
    "clientNumber": 222,
    "productType": "electronics"
  }
]
```

This query won't match any of them:

`clientNumber:565 AND productType:electronics`

But I'm interested in documents that match those restrictions within the same `businessObjectId` - not within a single document. Given provided example I want my query to return first two documents. I am aware I can flatten my model into:

```
[
  {
    "businessObjectId": 4,
    "contractNumber": [421, 455]
    "clientNumber": [565],
    "productType": ["electronics"]
  },
  {
    "businessObjectId": 5,
    "clientNumber": [222],
    "productType": ["electronics"]
  }
]
```

But this time I'm loosing the ability to sort. I assume my schema needs to be fixed anyway in order to achieve this but I'm looking for some clues. Can any good thing come out from nesting my objects?

Comment: You can still sort multi-fields.

Comment: How many documents would potentially match?

Comment: Up to 1k on a regular basis, worst case conditions might be much higher